# Arrange data based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I receive a workbook that has employee information including: number of people in family, date of birth and relationship to employee (ie spouse, child).  I am looking for a formula to distinguish families that have multiple children in a specific format.  I tried `INDEX(MATCH` but the formula cant distinguish two different children because the relationship to employee is the same.

Relationship to employee meanings:

- 1=self
- 2=spouse
- 3=children

My workbook:

[image: enter code here]

Desired result:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant way but it is simple and it would work.

First You need to make the children unique. To do that you need to

1. Add `=A2&D2` to `E2`. This will be your lookup value
2. Add `=INT(IF(D2=3,D2&COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2),D2))` to `F2`

Then you can either go ahead with your `index(match` formula matching 31, 32 etc instead of 3. Else create a pivot table with

- Employee name as row label
- Relationship as column
- DOB as values (Take max instead of count)
- Goto `value field settings` > `Number format` and format the values as date
- Change the labels on top to Spouse DOB, child DOB etc.